# Problems using PyCaret for time series

Tags: python, time-series, conda, pycaret

I am new to python and want to use Pycaret to analyze time series. I created a conda environment and installed pycaret via `conda install pycaret-ts-alpha`.
But then, when I want to execute `from pycaret.time_series import *` I get the following error:

ImportError: cannot import name '_check_param_grid' from 'sklearn.model_selection._search' (C:\Users\diego\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_search.py)'

I would really appreciate some help

Comment: You have a user-level Python installation that includes an incompatible version of `scikit-learn` and it is masking the (presumably) compatible version installed in the Conda environment. Duplicate provides multiple options for resolving.